# Can't understand use of Elimination of Contradiction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

First, I'm sorry for posting pictures instead of writing.
[image]

This is supposed to illustrate how we can prove by contradiction. My problem is with line 3, it could be anything. If instead of ~Q it was just Q would it still be valid?

Here's another case where it is used. The premises are (P v Q) and ~P and the goal is Q.
[image]

My problem is with the 4th step, just as ~Q was assumed couldn't it just be Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're overlooking is that you have a *goal* you are trying to reach.

In the first proof, if you assumed $Q$ in line 3, then your conclusion in line 5 would be $\neg Q$. This is great if $\neg Q$ is what you were actually trying to prove, but is completely useless if your goal is to prove $Q$.

Comment: Thanks, so that means we can assume anything inside a contradiction. This method seems like we're cheating since we control the outcome. Does this have any implications in non-abstract cases?

Comment: @krystalgamer: The principle at work here is called the *principle of explosion* -- from a contradiction you can derive anything. It's useful for making proofs more systematic. For example, the second proof in your post use "proof by cases", splitting on the cases with premise $P$ and premise $Q$. People often make some ad-hoc argument that the first case "can't happen" and so we can ignore it. You don't need to resort to any such thing, though, since in that case you can simply invoke explosion to arrive at the goal, as demonstrated in the posted proof.